# Angular js losing binding after jquery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am using angular to add some functionality to convert date in another framework (OutSystems). Unfortunately, the framework is calling jquery .load() to do Ajax refresh. This essentially is causing angular binding to break. I do not have any directives or controller. Please find code below. On launching page first tme you should see datetime of Feb 18, 2016 9:51:29 AM but after clicking button and calling.load() it just shows {{ 1455807089244 | date:'medium': 'EST' }}. I tried to use $compiler but it's still doesn't bind. Any help/hint is appreciated. 
*Note: This a "Test example" to demonstrate the problem.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

        function reload() {
            $('#div1').load('/index.html #divInner');

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="div1">
        <div id="divInner">
            <label id="L1">Hello {{ 1455807089244  | date:'medium': 'EST' }} </label>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button"
           onclick="reload();" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't do that! that isn't the right way to do angular.

Comment: If all you are using angular for is to filter dates it makes no sense to use angular which is a framework not a library

Comment: @DanielA.White, This is just a test example to get the point across. I absolutely understand this is not the way to do it :-)

Comment: @charlietfl. I wish I had that choice. Unfortunately, I have to work in Outsystems and want to use angular functionality for a few things. Now, given the situation, what are your thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts are you are using conflicting frameworks

Comment: @charlietfl: Agree 100%. Now we got that out of the way, do you have any suggestion for rebinding angular if any DOM elements are reloaded like in example?  Another thing is, .load is called by code which is beyond my control.

Comment: No...whatever you are doing needs to be done in context of the master framework you are using. Using `load` in angular makes no sense when there are numerous other ways built in to load content from data models, routing and directives

Comment: @charlietfl. but the master framework is limited. and I get your point though. and I am not calling .load(). It is called by some hidden framework code. If I had choice, I will just write everything in angular. In fact, the I am porting application from angular to OutSystems. and I didn't make that decision.

Comment: I know little about `Outsystems ` but if you must use it then angular is probably a bad choice because you really can't use angular on top of a jQuery based ajax framework. Most likely there are alternatives for whatever features you are trying to incorporate

Comment: I am converting an application written in angular and Java MVC to OutSystems. That's where I am leveraging few things from original angular code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104061/discussion-between-user2619299-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

I think cracked this one... FYI, I have been working on this for days

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

        app.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $compile) {
            $.fn.reload = function (url, selector) {
                $(selector).load(url, function () {
                    var elem = angular.element($(selector));
                    elem.replaceWith($compile(elem)($scope));
                    $scope.$apply();
                });


            };
        });



    </script>
</head>
<body >

    <div id="div1">
        <div id="divInner">
            <label id="L1">Hello {{ 1455807089244  | date:'medium': 'EST' }} </label>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button"
           onclick="$().reload('/index.html #divInner', '#div1') " />

</body>
</html>
```